# Are there any shorthand pseudo class variants in tailwind?

Tags: tailwind-css

While using [tailwind](https://tailwindcss.com/), is it possible to change the [pseudo-class-variants](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/pseudo-class-variants) to be shorthand?

For example:
`.hover:bg-blue-500` would be `.h:bg-blue-500`

I think this would greatly decrease the string length of a class attribute.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible by default.

You probably should write a custom plugin to add your variant

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuring-variants/

Answer (score 0):

there is someone that make shorthand for tailwind, u can check this git
https://github.com/sumanthyedoti/tw-shorthand